# A book in iBooks won't finish deleting.

Tags: ipad, books

When tidying my downloaded iBooks (not all from the Apple Store)my iPad got stuck trying to remove a download. I now cannot purchase any more books because my iPad won't complete the deleting process. I've tried signing out of my iTunes account and signing in again. Holding down the power and home buttons until the Apple logo appears. Nothing seems to work. I have, however, yet to update to iOS 11.0.3 will this resolve the issue I'm having with iBooks, once I complete the update?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Settings app > iTunes&App Stores. Check to see if automatic downloads are turned on for iBooks. If so, turn it off.